# How can I restore the automatic location bar focus with Firefox 13?

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts, firefox-extensions, browser-tabs

Safari does it, Chrome does it, and Firefox did it up to version 12: put the focus automatically to the location bar (a.k.a. address bar) when opening a new tab.

With FF13 this behaviour changed, probably due to the new [New Tab Page](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/new-tab-page-show-hide-and-customize-top-sites). It doesn't matter if the **newtabpage** configuration is enabled or not, when you press Cmd-T (or Ctrl-T) the focus is nowhere and you have to press Cmd-L before you can start typing.

Is there a configuration option to revert to the old behaviour?

Comment: You are certain it isn't related to any extensions/user-scripts customizations that you already have?  Did you double check with a clean install, perhaps with a portable apps version of Firefox?

Comment: @Zoredache you're right, disabling the extensions one by one found the culprit, see the answer below. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Zoredache (see comment) is right. The problem is not with Firefox, but with the [WebMail Notifier](http://webmailnotifier.mozdev.org/) extension (version 2.9.7).

And it's a known problem; see the [Mozilla bug entry 718918](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=718918) and the [webmailnotifier bug entry 24668](https://www.mozdev.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=24668).

Comment: WebMail Notifier 2.9.8 (release yesterday?) has fixed the problem :-)